# Evaluating $\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-1}\right)-\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k}-1}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

This essentially translates to $\left(\dfrac{1}{3^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{5^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{7^2-1}+\cdots\right)-\left(\dfrac{1}{9^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{25^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{27^2-1}\cdots\right)$

I used a method I'm not too sure about.
I assumed the trigonometric series:

$\cos(x)\cos(x/3)\cos(x/5)\cos(x/7)\cos(x/9)\cdots$

The coefficients of $x^2$ in the entire series is

$\left(\dfrac{-1}{2}\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\cdots\right)=\dfrac{-\pi^2}{16}$

Deprecating the cos series into infinite products:

$$\begin{split}&\cos(x)\cos(x/3)\cos(x/5)\cos(x/7)\cos(x/9)\cdots\\ &=(\cos(x/1))(\cos(x/3)\cos(x/9)\cos(x/27)\cos(x/81)\cdots)\\
&\quad\,\,(\cos(x/5)\cos(x/25)\cos(x/125)\cdots)(\cos(x/7)\cos(x/49)\cos(x/343)\cdots)(\cdots)\cdots\end{split}$$

Individually the coefficients of $x^2$ are

$\cos(x)$ gives $\dfrac{-1}{2}$;

$\cos(x/3)$ series gives $\dfrac{-1}{2(3^2-1)}$ (Infinite GPs, $\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{9^2}+\cdots$)

$\cos(x/5)$ series gives $\dfrac{-1}{2(5^2-1)}\cdots$

So the summation of the coefficients should equal $\dfrac{-\pi^2}{16}$ (Since $\cos(x)$ expansion is $1+a2x^2+\cdots$, the coefficients should be added individually)

So,
$\dfrac{1}{1}+\dfrac{1}{3^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{5^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{7^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{11^2-1}+\dfrac{1}{13^2-1}\cdots=\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}\simeq1.233$

The value manually calculated upto $n=10$ gives $\simeq1.2125$

However I'm not sure if this method is valid or correct. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could rectify the errors or errenous assumptions in the derivation.

Comment: Do you mean evaluate $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-1}\right)-\left(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2k}-1}\right)$$?

Comment: Please avoid using displaystyle size font (this includes dfrac) in your titles, see this [Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/1104384).

Comment: Actually, I haven't got what you want to ask? Question in title is different than you did 

Comment: Just the sum of the reciprocals of all odd numbers (with the exception of numbers of the form $3^4,3^6,3^8\cdots$) squared minus 1.

Comment: The partial sum of the first term gives $\frac{N}{4(N+1)}$ by Wolfram Alpha, which converges to $\frac{1}{4}$ for $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: You wrote "I assumed the trigonometric series: $\cos(x)\cos(x/3)\cos(x/5)\cos(x/7)\cos(x/9)\cdots$". First, that's not a series, it's an infinite product. Second, one assumes **facts** about expressions, it makes no sense talking about assuming an expression. My guess is you meant to say "I considered the trigonometric infinite product"

Comment: You also may want to check the meaning of the word "deprecating"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{a^2-1}$$ The summation becomes:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2r} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2rk}
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2r} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2rk}
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2r}} - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2rk}}\right)
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2r}} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2r}[(2n+1)^{2r} - 1]}\right)
$$

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{(2n+1)^{2r}} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2r}-1}\right)
$$

I unfortunately couldn't work out a "nice" closed-form expression for the latter term.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2r}-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(2n+1)^r-1} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^r+1}\right)
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{ln(2n+1)-ln(2n)-\psi_{\frac{1}{2n+1}}(1)}{ln(2n+1)} - \frac{\psi_{\frac{1}{2n+1}}(1-\frac{i\cdot\pi}{ln(2n+1)}) + ln(2n) - ln(2n+1)}{ln(2n+1)}\right)
$$

$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{-\psi_{\frac{1}{2n+1}}(1) + \psi_{\frac{1}{2n+1}}(1-\frac{i\cdot\pi}{ln(2n+1)})}{ln(2n+1)}\right)
$$

where $\psi_{q}(z)$ is the q-digamma function.

It appears to be very difficult to evaluate that by hand (although I'm not very sure, maybe it can be done but I may be missing something). According to computer algebra system, this summation is roughly around $0.2664584502$. So, if we use that we obtain:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2n+1)^{2r}} - 0.2664584502
$$

$$
2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^{2} - 1} - 0.2664584502
$$

$$
2\cdot \frac{1}{4} - 0.266 = 0.23354
$$